# What is here the recommended way the get rid of the "v-string in use/require non-portable" warning?

Tags: perl, version, warnings, perl5.10

A module requires at least Perl 5.10.0.

When I use this module with Perl version 5.10.0 I get the warning:

```
v-string in use/require non-portable at ... (line of "use 5.10.0;").
```

In Perl 5.10.1 this warning is removed.

What would be the recommended way to avoid the warning:

```
- change all "use 5.10.0" in the distro to "use 5.010_000;"

- add "no warnings 'portable';" to the module

- leave it to the user of Perl 5.10.0 to add "no warnings 'portable';"

- Increase the smallest required version to 5.10.1.
```

---

```
perl -wE 'use 5.10.0; say $^V'
# v-string in use/require non-portable at -e line 1.
# v5.10.0
```

Comment: Cannot replicate this on my system. Perhaps you should create a small code sample that replicates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything from 5.10.0 and later, you don't need to specify a minor version:

```
use v5.10;
```

You might consider using at least 5.10.1, which had some significant changes to the earlier minor version (including fixing your warning):

```
use v5.10.1;
```

But, give us a sample program, show use which Perl you're using and all that other stuff.

Comment: I'm curious; wouldn't "`use 5.010001;`" be considered a better practice since the use of v-strings is still controversial?

Comment: I will "use 5.10.1;".

Comment: @tchrist got me into the habit I show when we were working on Programming Perl. I don't use v-strings for anything else.